# windows batch/ windows cmd loop parameters with variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to make a Windows (7) batch script with variables in the parameters, and i keep on getting error's, is there someone who knows how to solve this?

```
@ECHO OFF
::::   settings   ::::
SET "InputFile=D:\somefile.ext"
SET "linesToSkipCharacter="
SET "endOfLineCharacter="
SET "RowNoToRead=1"
SET "delimiterCharacter=;"
::::::::::::::::::::::

:: make shore the variables are emty
SET "linesToSkip=" "endOfLine=" "tokens=" "delims="

:: if set put parameter into variable
if not "%delimiterCharacter%"=="" SET "delims=delims=%delimiterCharacter% "
if not "%linesToSkipCharacter%"=="" if not "%linesToSkipCharacter%"=="0" SET "linesToSkip=skip=%linesToSkipCharacter% "
if not "%endOfLineCharacter%"=="" if not "%endOfLineCharacter%"=="0" SET "endOfLine=eol=%endOfLineCharacter% "
if not "%RowNoToRead%"=="" if not "%RowNoToRead%"=="0" SET "tokens=tokens=%RowNoToRead%"

:: loop File with the given parameters 
fOR /F "%delims%%linesToSkip%%endOfLine%%tokens%" %%A IN (%InputFile%) DO echo do something with %%A
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incorrectly setting `linesToSkip` to `" "endOfLine=" "tokens=" "delims=`.
Only `SET /a` can be used to initialize multiple variables in a comma-separated list but not in this case as there is nothing to assign/calculate.

Use the correct syntax:

```
SET "linesToSkip=" & SET "endOfLine=" & SET "tokens=" & SET "delims="
```

P.S. Remove `@echo off` and run the batch file from Command Prompt console to see the errors.